# How can get difterence of date in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I correct below statement

```
SELECT datediff(day, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2))
```

and

```
SELECT  dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2)))
```

I want to convert ms-sql statement into snowflake

```
SELECT datediff(day, 0, getdate())
```

and

```
SELECT  dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, getdate()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake DATEDIFF function returns the difference between 2 dates thus it doesn't accept NUMBER as an argument in place of a date. MSSQL on the other hand does an implicit cast of '0' to DATE '1900-01-01' and returns the result in the requested date part.
In Snowflake you can rewrite the query :

```
SELECT datediff(day, '1900-01-01', CURRENT_DATE);
```

DATEADD function takes a DATE as input and adds the requested number of date parts to that very DATE. `DATEADD( <date_or_time_part>, <value>, <date_or_time_expr> )`
For more information refer to [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html#syntax).